# Why are span's array and std::array constructors different from its container constructors

Tags: c++, c++20, std-span

I have been playing around with the latest specification for `std::span` using the clang trunk and libc++ on Godbolt and find some of the constructors confusing.

In particular I find the constructors from a plain old array and and a `std::array` to be different from other containers.

For example the following code appears to compile:

```
std::vector<int*> v = {nullptr, nullptr};
std::span<const int* const> s{v};
```

However this does not:

```
std::array<int*, 2> a = {nullptr, nullptr}; 
std::span<const int* const> s{a};
```

This seems to be in keeping with [the way the constructors are described on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span), I am just struggling to understand why this is the case. Can anybody shed any light?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems like an oversight. The array constructors are currently specified as:

```
template<size_t N> constexpr span(array<value_type, N>& arr) noexcept;
template<size_t N> constexpr span(const array<value_type, N>& arr) noexcept;
```

But should probably be specified as:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
    requires std::convertible_to<T(*)[], ElementType(*)[]>
  constexpr span(array<T, N>& arr) noexcept;
template<class T, size_t N>
    requires std::convertible_to<const T(*)[], ElementType(*)[]>
  constexpr span(const array<T, N>& arr) noexcept;
```

Which would make your example compile, as it is safe to do. I submitted an LWG issue. This is now [LWG 3255](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3255).

---

The wording *already* has this constraint specified in [[span.cons]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/span.cons#11.2):

> ```
> template<size_t N> constexpr span(element_type (&arr)[N]) noexcept;
> template<size_t N> constexpr span(array<value_type, N>& arr) noexcept;
> template<size_t N> constexpr span(const array<value_type, N>& arr) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Constraints*:
>
> - `extent == dynamic_­extent || N == extent` is `true`, and
> - `remove_­pointer_­t<decltype(data(arr))>(*)[]` is convertible to `ElementType(*)[]`.

So we already have the right constraint. It's just that `data(arr)` isn't actually dependent in any of these cases, so the constraint is trivially satisfied. We just need to make these templates.

Comment: Surprisingly the documentation does state it: _"These overloads only participate in overload resolution if extent == std::dynamic_extent || N == extent is true **and std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(std::data(arr))>(*)[] is convertible to element_type (*)[]**"_

Comment: @Timo Oh, weird. Yeah, we do have that wording... except the underlying type of the arrays isn't a template...

Comment: This is exactly what I found confusing, especially the specific choice of element_type for plain old arrays and value_type for arrays. Why would they be different?